# Deserialize json c# with CRM 365 API

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dynamic, crm

[image: I have a JSON string of this format:]

So, I've made classes like this:

```
public class Values
{
    public string odata_context { get; set; }
    public List<ContactsDeserialize> keyValues { get; set; }
}
public class ContactsDeserialize : IDisposable
{
    public string odata_etag     { get; set; }
    public Guid contactid        { get; set; }
    public string crimson_title  { get; set; }
    public string firstname      { get; set; }
    public string lastname       { get; set; }
    public DateTime? createdon   { get; set; }
    public DateTime? birthdate   { get; set; }
    public string emailaddress1  { get; set; }
    public string mobilephone    { get; set; }
    public string address1_line1 { get; set; }
    public string address1_line2 { get; set; }
    public string address1_line3 { get; set; }
    public string address1_city  { get; set; }
    public string address1_postalcode { get; set; }
    public string address1_telephone1 { get; set; }
}
```

but when I try to deserialise 
this by using

```
Values ContactData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Values>(jsonstring);
```

it's return null.
Can not find out the reason

Thanks

Comment: Is the Json formatted correctly? I've had it a few times that depending on how the result is getting returned the objects might not be separated by commas, which would break the deserialization.

Answer (score 1):

Your class fields a little bit differ to original json fields, so if you want to use this you need to put attributes to your fields to provide correct json fields i.e

```
[JsonProperty("@odata.etag")]
public string odata_etag { get; set; }
```

for more details see the documentation [article](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Could be that you need to intialise the keyValues list in a constructor.

```
public class Values
{
    public Values()
    {
         keyValues = new List<ContactsDeserialize>();
    }

    public string odata_context  {get; set; }
    public List<ContactsDeserialize> keyValues { get; set; }
}
```

Alos the names of you objects should match exactly what the json return unless you define what it maps to in an attribute. Both odata_context and keyValues are named slightly different to how they are returned in the json.

Answer (score -1):

You declare `public List<ContactsDeserialize> keyValues { get; set; }` in Class Values,but the node of your json is value.

Comment: The result is returning two objects, keyValues and odata_context. Which values contains.

Comment: I mean that the variable is named "keyValues" ，but the node of json relative is named value. I wonder how can json be deserialized when names are not the same.